# List repos of a user

Tags: python, github3.py

Hey I've been reading up on the github3.py, but can't find a clear explanation of how to retrieve a list of a user's repositories.

It seems that there should be a simple solution like a method or a attribute to the user object. I just can't seem to find it on the docs, can anyone help?

Thanks,
Van

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GitHub.iter_user_repos`](https://github3py.readthedocs.org/en/master/github.html#github3.github.GitHub.iter_user_repos):

> `iter_user_repos(login, type=None, sort=None, direction=None, number=-1, etag=None)`
>
> List public repositories for the specified login.
>
> New in version 0.6.

It's a bit odd that this isn't a method of the User object - you might want to submit an issue to have that added to the API.