# How to a list of repos belonging to a user in github?

Tags: github, github-api

For each user in github, there is "repositories" number which is owned by the user:

[image]

How do we enumerate all these repos programmatically?

There is a API called "https://api.github.com/users/{username}/repos" which can enumerate some of the repos, but it is not a complete list - as it is not listing a lot of the repos which I had created and is listed at the github.com website.

PS:

A somewhat similar question is asked here:   [List repos of a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30962089/list-repos-of-a-user) but its answer is also not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the GitHub cli [`gh repo list`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_list) command should help.

It should manage the [API pagination](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/using-pagination-in-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28), and return a full list.

The [OP Peter Teoh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315046/peter-teoh) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75444198/how-to-a-list-of-repos-belonging-to-a-user-in-github/75444811#comment133724578_75444811):

> To be precise, by default only 30 are listed, so I put "`gh repo list -L 1000`": a large number like 1000 as the max limit to list all.

Comment: Yes, to be precise, default only 30 are listed, so I put "gh repo list -L 1000" a large number like 1000 as the max limit to list all.